# What is a good icon / graphical way to represent 'closed', 'terminated', 'ended', 'expired'... etc?

Tags: icon

I've seen some questions here bump into similar 'time' related icon problems (since 'termination' is sort of a time related concept, similar to 'the past')

It doesn't *have* to be an icon either, since I've been thinking about 'strikethrough'. (but that also interferes a bit with legibility / accessibility in our case, similar to 'fading'... so Ideally if there was an icon I'm just not seeing would be ideal!)

Searching around I found some icons like 'clocks' and 'x' icons, but those don't *really* match perfectly either... any ideas?.

The exact case here is for a type of 'document', so I think something like 'terminate contract' (via thenounproject) is the closest i'll get!

[image]

Comment: It would probably depend on context.  What is the icon representing, the end of what?  Have a look at the nounproject website. Use it to search for common terms such as: end, finish, stop, complete, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about thenounproject! (I've usually just searched for fontawesome icons)

Comment: if you make the question about a specific context that you want to use this icon/representation it will be less broad and you might get better answers. As it is there will be different representations for different contexts and the question is too broad.